# Flutter onForcePress() of `GestureDectector() is not a callback

Tags: flutter

I'm using the `onForcePressStart()` of the Gesture Detector to detect the pressure of touch, apple pen, etc.

I tested with the following code and `onForcePress()` is not invoked when touching or dragging.

```
GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            logger.d("onTap"); // ok
          },
          // not call
          onForcePressPeak: (details) {
            logger.d("onForcePressPeak");
          },
          onForcePressStart: (details) {
            logger.d("onForcePressStart");
          },
          onForcePressUpdate: (details) {
            logger.d("onForcePressUpdate");
            logger.d("press: ${details.pressure}");
          },
          onForcePressEnd: (details) {
            logger.d("onForcePressEnd");
          },
          child: Container(
            width: 300,
            height: 300,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
        ),
```

Is this used incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should press with more strength.

seen from the source code:

from `class GestureDetector extends StatelessWidget {`

`onForcePressPeak` is function of `ForcePressGestureRecognizer`

```
 if (onForcePressStart != null ||
        onForcePressPeak != null ||
        onForcePressUpdate != null ||
        onForcePressEnd != null) {
      gestures[ForcePressGestureRecognizer] = GestureRecognizerFactoryWithHandlers<ForcePressGestureRecognizer>(
        () => ForcePressGestureRecognizer(debugOwner: this),
        (ForcePressGestureRecognizer instance) {
          instance
            ..onStart = onForcePressStart
            ..onPeak = onForcePressPeak
            ..onUpdate = onForcePressUpdate
            ..onEnd = onForcePressEnd;
        },
      );
    }
```

then, when `onForcePressPeak`  of `GestureDetector`  gets called,

namely, when `onPeak`  of `ForcePressGestureRecognizer` gets called,

from `class ForcePressGestureRecognizer extends OneSequenceGestureRecognizer {`, you can see the usage condition.

```
 if (onPeak != null && pressure > peakPressure &&
         (_state == _ForceState.started)) {
        _state = _ForceState.peaked;
        if (onPeak != null) {
          invokeCallback<void>('onPeak', () => onPeak!(ForcePressDetails(
            pressure: pressure,
            globalPosition: event.position,
            localPosition: event.localPosition,
          )));
        }
      }
```

the key condition is `pressure > peakPressure`

also from `class ForcePressGestureRecognizer`,

```
  ForcePressGestureRecognizer({
    this.startPressure = 0.4,
    this.peakPressure = 0.85,

...
```

and

```
  /// The pressure of the press required to peak a force press.
  ///
  /// A value of 0.0 is no pressure, and 1.0 is maximum pressure. This value
  /// must be greater than [startPressure].
  final double peakPressure;
```

you just need to ***try it harder***.